NE555 PWM Circuit Problem
I am using NE555 in a care-over project for generate PWM. But i have a problem. On this 12V input path, there is 4.2V on the R1 resistor, although it is expected to be 11.6V. What could be the reason for this voltage drop here?
Full schema:


The connections that may explain where the current might go are cropped out of the picture. Have you tried to measure the circuit in any way to find where the current flows?

There is 5V voltage on the discharge pin @Justme

On which side of the resistor there is 4.2V then? Or is there 4.2V over the resistor, so there is 5V on DISCH side and 9.2V on the diode side? Have you checked if the diode is damaged?

You need to show us the full schematic around the 555 with measurements. Whether you crop the schematic better or use the sites built in editor. The capacitor is not shown.

Some oscilloscope waveforms would be illustrative as well; DISCH is a digital output pin, it doesn't make sense for it to read an intermediate voltage -- except as an average over time, which must be the case here. Likely, this fact will be relevant to the given question too.

Full schema is available on the post  @StainlessSteelRat

I solved the problem. The problem was that the diode outputs were connected to the wrong legs of the trimpot in pcb.
Thanks for yor supports,
speedy
